# NSTextStorageDelegate's textStorage(_,willProcessEditing:,range:,changeInLength:) moves selection

Tags: macos, swift3, syntax-highlighting, nstextview, nstextstorage

I'm trying to implement a syntax-coloring text editor that also does things like insert whitespace at the start of a new line for you, or replace text with text attachments.

After perusing the docs again after a previous implementation had issues with undoing, it seems like the recommended bottleneck for this is NSTextStorageDelegate's textStorage(_,willProcessEditing:,range:,changeInLength:) method (which states that `Delegates can change the characters or attributes.`, whereas `didProcessEditing` says I can *only* change attributes). This works fine, *except* that whenever I actually change attributes or text, the text insertion mark moves to the end of whatever range of text I modify (so if I change the style of the entire line, the cursor goes at the end of the line).

Does anybody know what additional call(s) I am missing that tell NSTextStorage/NSTextView not to screw up the insertion mark? Also, once I insert text, I might have to tell it to move the insertion mark to account for text I've inserted.

**Note:** I've seen [Modifying NSTextStorage causes insertion point to move to the end of the line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12151360/modifying-nstextstorage-causes-insertion-point-to-move-to-the-end-of-the-line), but that assumes I'm subclassing NSTextStorage, so I can't use the solution there (and would rather not subclass NSTextStorage, as it's a semi-abstract subclass and I'd lose certain behaviours of Apple's class if I subclassed it).

Comment: Did you see the last comment in the linked question?

Comment: You mean the "use didProcess instead of willProcess?" Yes, but that 1. refers to the old, deprecated willProcess:/didProcess: *notification methods* and 2. would be against Apple's docs, which clearly state that I may only change the text from willProcess.

Comment: If you mean "do read the documentation warnings about leaving the textStorage in an inconsistent state", I can't find those :-(

Comment: You could have mentioned this in the question.

Comment: I tried this and the insertion point doesn't move. How do you change the text?

Comment: Right now I only call NSTextStorage addAttribute on the range for the line where the edit occurred. (Not just on the edited range)

Comment: The layout manager "fixes" the selection. Maybe you can fix the selection again in `textDidChange(_:)` of `NSTextDelegate`.

Comment: Just tried that. Apparently the fixing happens after textDidChange(_, didProcessEditing:,range:,changeInLength:).

Comment: The fixing happens before `textDidChange(_:)`.

Comment: I was referring to the selected range being changed by NSTextStorage. I saved it at the start of will, restored at the end of did, no dice. textDidChange(_:) is deprecated. What call are you referring to, if that doesn't work?

Comment: I'm referring to [textDidChange(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstextdelegate/1526982-textdidchange) of `NSTextDelegate`, the superprotocol of `NSTextViewDelegate`. `textDidChange(_:)` of `NSTableView` is deprecated.

Comment: How do I find out what changed from that call, though?

Comment: Ah, I guess I can combine the two messages, save away the editedRange etc. and then access it from textDidChange.

Comment: Yes, calculate the new insertion point in `textStorage(_,willProcessEditing:,range:,changeInLength:)` and set it in `textDidChange(_:)`.

Comment: @uliwitness can you share your solution as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out the source of the problem.

And the only solution that will work robustly based on reasons inherent to the Cocoa framework instead of mere work-arounds. (Note there's probably at least one other, metastable approach based on a *ton* of quick-fixes that produces a similar result, but as metastable alternatives go, that'll be very fragile and require a ton of effort to maintain.)

- TL;DR Problem: **`NSTextStorage` collects `edited` calls and combines the ranges, starting with the user-edited change (e.g. the insertion), then adding all ranges from `addAttributes(_:range:)` calls during highlighting.**
- TL;DR Solution: Perform highlighting from `textDidChange(_:)` exclusively.

### Details

[image: What happens when you type and change style]

This only applies to a single `processEditing()` run, both in `NSTextStorage` subclasses and in `NSTextStorageDelegate` callbacks.

The only safe way to perform highlighting I found is to hook into `NSText.didChangeNotification` or implement `NSTextDelegate.textDidChange(_:)`.

As per @Willeke's comments to the OP's question, this is the best place to perform changes after the layout pass. But as opposed to the comment thread, setting back `NSText.selectedRange` does not suffice. You won't notice the problem of post-fixing the selection after the caret has moved away until

- you highlight whole blocks of text,
- spanning multiple lines, and
- exceeding the visible (`NSClipView`) boundaries of the scroll view.

In this rare case, most keystrokes will make the scroll view jiggle or bounce around. But there's no additional quick-fix against this. I tried. Neither preventing sending the scroll commands from private API in `NSLayoutManager` nor avoiding scrolling by overriding all methods with "scroll" in them from a `NSTextView` subclass works well. You can stop scrolling to the insertion point altogether, sure, but no such luck getting a solid algorithm out that does not scroll only when you perform highlighting.

The `didChangeNotification` approach does work reliably in all situations I and my app's testers were able to come up with (including a crash situation as weird as scrolling the text and then, during the animation, replacing the string with something shorter -- yeah, try to figure that kind of stuff out from crash logs that report invalid glyph generation ...).

This approach works because it does 2 glyph generation passes:

1. One pass for the edited range, in the case of typing for every key stroke with a `NSRange` of length 1, sending the `edited` notification with both `[.editedCharacters, .editedAttributes]`, the former being responsible for moving the caret;
2. another pass for whatever range is affected by syntax highlighting, sending the `edited` notification with `[.editedAttributes]` only, thus *not* affecting the caret's position at all.

### Even more details

In case you want to know more about the source of the problem, I put more my research, different approaches, and details of the solution in a much longer blog post for reference. This here, though, is the solution itself.  http://christiantietze.de/posts/2017/11/syntax-highlight-nstextstorage-insertion-point-change/

Answer (score 0):

The above accepted answer with the notification center worked for me, but I had to include one more thing when editing text. (Which may be different from selection).

The `editedRange` of the `NSTextStorage` was whack after the notification center callback. So I keep track of the last known value myself by overriding the `processEditing` function and using that value later when I get the callback.

```swift
override func processEditing() {
        // Hack.. the editedRange property when reading from the notification center callback is weird
        lastEditedRange = editedRange
        super.processEditing()
    }
```